# Android: open dialog on adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

How do I open a DialogFragment inside a RecyclerView Adapter, or how do I do it through the main activity? I need to open it by clicking on every view that is added into the RecyclerView.

Comment: The easiest way is to add callback when creating adapter.

Comment: Ok I'm looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set this on the DialogFragment:**

```
 public static myFragment newInstance() {
    return new myFragment();
}
```

**Set this on the adapter:**

```
public Activity mcontext;

public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context) {
// Here we're getting the activity's context, 
// by setting the adapter on the activity with (this)   
this.mcontext=context;

}
```

**Show it in through the adapter like this:**

```
 myFragment newFragment = myFragment.newInstance();
 newFragment.show(mcontext.getFragmentManager(), "Title");
```

Comment: getFragmentManager() Can not resolve. please help me

Comment: How are you trying?

Comment: see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802070/show-fragmentdialog-in-recyclerview-adapter

Answer (score 2):

Inside your RecyclerviewAdapter, and in the onClick method of the view (the view that clicked shows this dialog), u can place the below code.
Edited:

```
MyDialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
newFragment.show(((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Title");
```

Note: the "context" is the context of the activity from where the recyclerview is created. (the context variable passed as an argument in the cnstructor of RecyclerviewAdapter.)

Note2: MyDialogFragment is a dialogfragment that u created. In this MyDialogFragment u should have the constructor newInstance()

The MyDialogFragment can look like this:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
    MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();

    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myDialog, null))
            .setTitle("Title")
            ...
           // Set ur code 

    return builder.create();
   }
}
```

So now for how to pass the context, from the mainActivity, when u create the adapter n the activity context that u pass to the adapter is the context i m talking about.
For Example: the "this" in the code below is the activity context that u will be passing to your adapter. This code is present in ur MainActivity.

```
 MyAdapter adapter1 = new MyAdapter(this, array_list);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: Ok two issues, it cannot resolve `newInstance` and how do I pass the context from the activity?

Comment: the layout file " fragment_myDialog.xml " can have ur dialog layout containing the  Textview, editText  and button

Comment: Ok one problem, I cannot pass the `array_list` into the new adapter, the list is called `items`

Comment: array_list is ur items list variable, so whats the problem ? Can u post ur code where u define ur adapter (MyAdapter as in my code), so that ur problem is more clear.

Comment: here's [MyAdapter](http://imgur.com/3ePZa2k) and here's the [Viewholder](http://imgur.com/6FnPJNI) What I'm not geting right is the line `MyAdapter adapter1 = new MyAdapter(this, items);` because it can't resolve `items`

Comment: Where have u defined ur class Viewholder? inside the MyAdapter or in the MainActivity? U need to place a constructor in your adapter - MyAdapter. And also the Viewholder class does not have any activity of its own but in order to create the Dialog fragment any class needs the activity context which should be passed from the calling activity. Thats why we need a constructor in the adapter class that takes the activity context from its super class (the calling MainActivity).

Comment: So write down a constructor for the Adapter which takes the activity context as the first argument and the items list as second. The second step is to pass this context to the ViewHolder class which can then use this context to create the DialogFragment.

Comment: I have the ViewHolder inside the Adapter, I took two separate prints because it was too large. Ok I've set a constructor in the adapter `public MyAdapter(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }` but it still can't resolve the arrayList on the new adapter

Comment: How do we take the activity context in the contructor and pass it to the Viewholder?

Comment: There are two different methods that u can follow:                                          1) Use a global variable mcontext and assign it the activity context u received in the adapter constructor, Now u can use this mcontext in ur viewHolder.                                                                                                      2) shift the code of ur Gridbutton.setOnClickListener to the Adapter's method OnBindViewHolder.

Comment: And ur adapter constructor shud look like this                                             public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<String> items) { this.mcontext=context;                   this.items = items; }

Comment: Method 1) How do I first define the mContext so I can recieve it in the constructor?

Comment: Define the variable in the MyAdapter class like :                                                           final Activity mcontext;

Comment: this line `this.mcontext = Context;` is giving an error, "expression expected" on the Context

Comment: [Here it is](http://imgur.com/eosVTm7), if I changed `context` to mContext it woudnt resolve `getSupportFragmentManager`

Comment: I updated it to `this.mContext = context` in the custructor, and still doesn't resolve `gerSupportFragmentManager`

Comment: Ok I wasn't trying to show the Dialog in the right activity, now that I am, it can't resolve `show()` when trying to show it on the button's onClick. And I can't get the ArrayList when initiating the adapter in the activity

Comment: The adapter's constructor should be like this :-                                     public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<String> items) { this.mcontext=context;            this.items = items; }

Comment: And the dialog showing should be like this  : ---  
newFragment.show(((Activity) mcontext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "Title");

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Update: I changed `.getSupportFragmentManager` to `getFragmentManager`, it ran, but is crashing, the log error is _Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentManager android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager()' on a null object reference_, I set did `assert mcontext != null` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This is what I normally do when dealing with recyclerView items click events:

Create a click listener to reuse later.

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
   @SuppressWarnings("CanBeFinal")
   private OnItemClickListener mListener;

   public interface OnItemClickListener {
       void onItemClick(View view, int position);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("CanBeFinal")
   private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

   public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
       mListener = listener;
       mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
              return true;
           }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
       View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
       if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
           mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
       }
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

   }}
```

Then to use it in your Activity, do this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            showDialog();
        }
 }));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How do I change it to onLongClick? it should be obviously simple but I'm missing something.

Comment: Ok and one more thing, the view is composed by 1 textView, 1 EditText and 1 Button, it must only show the dialog when I click the button, not anywhere in the view, is this doable with your solution?

Comment: I can update my solution for you to handle that; but give me a moment

Comment: That a moment ahah

Comment: Sorry bro I traveled without notice!!